# Producing paired raster in FME?

Tags: raster, raster-calculator, fme-form

I want to use RasterCellValueCalculator in FME to perform an arithmetic operation on a pair of rasters (TIF).

FME requires that the two rasters must have the same number of rows and columns.

But my two raster have:

- different extent
- different size of pixel
- different number of rows and colums
  [image]

Which approach and transformers should I use to create a paired raster?

Comment: FME 2017 (1st March 2017) RasterMosaicker will have Interpolation for this https://docs.safe.com/fme/2017.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/rastermosaicker.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My raster manipulation in FME is limited. However, I would have a look at the following transformers which may assist you.

1. **[RasterPropertyExtractor](http://docs.safe.com/fme/2016.1/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/rasterpropertyextractor.htm)** - Extracts the geometry properties of a raster feature and exposes them as attributes.
2. **[RasterResampler](http://docs.safe.com/fme/2016.1/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/rasterresampler.htm)** - Resamples an input raster using the desired dimensions, the desired cell size in ground units, or a percentage of the size.
3. **[RasterSubsetter](http://docs.safe.com/fme/2016.1/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/rastersubsetter.htm)** - Reduces a raster to a subset of its original size. This is essentially a clipping operation using pixel bounds instead of ground coordinates.
4. **[RasterCellOriginSetter](http://docs.safe.com/fme/2016.1/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/rastercelloriginsetter.htm)** - Sets the raster's cell origin.